# First time app developer, attempting to add ActionBar broke everything

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

First time app developer and I'm trying to follow [the lovely tutorial provided by the nice guys at Google.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Everything was going well until I got to [the section on adding an ActionBar.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html)

I tried following the instruction for supporting Android 2.1 and above. I went to the SDK manager, installed v7 appcompat, set up a new library project, imported appcompat, imported appcompat, set up the build paths, configured build paths, yadda yadda. Basically I followed these steps to the letter: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Once that was done I adjusted MainActivity to extend ActionBarActivity and updated my manifest file to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` for the theme. Continuing with the tutorial I added an ActionBar with a search and settings button, but upon trying to compile I ran into nothing but errors. Originally my rampant ctrl+shift+O'ing had imported android.R - a problem I found an fixed. However after removing that import statement and going to Project > Clean it isn't generating the R.java file. I've looked through every resource and there are no files with a capital letter in the name. There's also no errors in my XML files, and every reference to `@string/<name>` exists in the strings.xml file

Any advice on what to try next would be appreciated. I can also post the contents of any file that you suspect may be the culprit. I've spent around 4 hours trying to debug this myself but I don't know where to go next.

For @bluebrain:

```
Description Resource Location Type
Unable to resolve target 'android-16' android-support-v7-appcompat Uknown Android Target Problem
```

For @Gem_Ram:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java (Every occurrence of R is giving me "R cannot be resolved to a variable"):

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                //openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java (same error):

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        setupActionBar();

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="action_search">Search</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>

</resources>
```

Any other files you'd like to see?

**Update:**

After changing `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` to `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;` I got a huge collection of red squigglies that I could not resolve since all of the methods I implemented and called are derivatives of the Activity class. I changed it back to `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` and hit save, then my Problems tab went berserk. First there were 63 problems, then 1, then 7, then 3, then 18... Problems ranging from some process failing with a negative return code, to variables being undefined, to some dependency not existing,... In an attempt to make Eclipse stop having a seizure I clicked Project > Clean, and now the old problem ("Unable to resolve target 'android-16'") is gone, and replaced by 7 instances of the problem "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Of course this is the problem I expected all along, since my R.java file isn't being generated.

Comment: can you please post what you see on errors and/or problems tab on eclipse?

Comment: @bluebrain: Added. It's an error in android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: are you using latest version of Android SDK (19 is the latest as far) ? if not, can you please update your SDK. Besides you can check these posts:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266803/1281930   http://stackoverflow.com/a/15804314/1281930 they looked promising.

Comment: I installed the Android SDK just this morning. In fact, my AndroidManifest.xml shows that I'm using SDK 19: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`. The number 16 doesn't even appear in my AndroidManifest.xml. I'll check out the SO link and see what it says.

Comment: Just opened the `project.properties` file and sure enough: `target=android-19`
`android.library.reference.1=../../../../Program Files/Android Developer Toolkit/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has the same issue as you mentioned here. I imported library adroid-support-v7-appcompat and error say:

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-16' android-support-v7-appcompat Uknown Android Target Problem
```

then I opened project.properties file in android-support-v7-appcompat project and edit line

```
target=android-19
```

to

```
target=android-16
```

I saved change and make change back to

```
target=android-19
```

I saved everything and project was recompiled and all errors disappeared. Now Im able to run project and everything look fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code. I've run this app successfully without any issues. For your reference, adding my files here:

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.actionbar.HelloWorldMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.actionbar.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.actionbar.HelloWorldMainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.actionbar.HelloWorldMainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ActionBarActivity file:

```
package com.example.actionbar;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ActionBarMainActivity extends Activity {

    //public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world_main);

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setUpActionBar() {
        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity File:

```
package com.example.actionbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.content.Intent;

public class HelloWorldMainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.actionbar.MESSAGE";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
        };
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab" + (i+1)).setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemsSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_call:
            openCall();
            return true;
        default: 
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void openCall() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openSettings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void openSearch() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">ActionBar</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_search">Search</string>
    <string name="action_call">Call</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">ActionBarMainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">DisplayMessageActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Just added the files to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Please update your "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;" to

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; in your MainActivity.java as you are using the support library APIs

And I hope your AVD is properly configured to min-7 and max-19 as per your manifest description.

In your project.properties file, ensure it has ===> target=android-19

Comment: My project.properties does, indeed, have target=android-19. Importing `ActionBar` instead of `ActionBarActivity` at first gave me a LOT of red squigglies since MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity. I changed it to extend ActionBar but I'm still getting a lot of red squigglies within the class. Mostly undefined methods.

Comment: Attempting to remove the red squigglies by going back to `ActionBarActivity` caused Eclipse to have a seizure. Details added to the bottom of my original post. Now my Problems tab looks different.