# Error while importing a project

Tags: android

I receive an error from my already successfully runned project, when I import it in another eclipse on a different system.

The error i get is:
`Can't resolve the target sdk"17"`.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266653/unable-to-resolve-target-android-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install/download API-17 in your SDK Manager to support your project. With such error, seems like your project is using API-17, and the API-17 is not supported by the new environment.

Comment: What,ll I do to support that,s projects on sdkmanager that support API level-18?