# Unable to resolve target 'android-17'

Tags: android, eclipse

I know there are some sort-of duplicates of this, but none of the answers have been able to help me so far.

When I open a project, I  get the following error:

```
 [2014-01-07 14:18:00 - Permissions] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
```

Does anybody know what may be the problem here?

Comment: Do you downloaded the API-17?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve target 'android-15'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15)

Comment: great visual explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266653/unable-to-resolve-target-android-16/27372810#27372810

Comment: If this problem is already solved, please consider marking one of the answers as correct to help others.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can right click on your project -> properties -> Android -> Select the Target android version you want to compile and Apply !

If you don't have any target versions to compile, you probably need to download them on your SDK Manager

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your Android SDK Manager, and make sure your SDK API is installed
2. You might have several Android SDK folders installed, like me; check that your workspace build path is the one your machine defaults to.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to use a library that was built using API 17 and you do not have it installed. If you are using API 18+ you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

goto your sdk manager.exe open it, check the  API 17 checkbox and click the 'install x packages' button, this will download and install these packages, if the project still shows error go in your project build path and fix the library path error if any

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the error can appear when you are working with source code built with an ADT that is a higher version than what you are currently using. It could be worth it to see if ADT has a later version than you are working. Sometimes ADT (especially with Eclipse. Link to get new here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) cannot find updates when asked to find them so you may need to install the newest version and overwrite/delete the old version

Answer (score 0):

The target API in project.properties may be different from the one you have installed. This may happen if you reinstall Eclipse, for example. Open the Android SDK Manager and check to see which version of the API you have installed. Then go to project.properties and set "target=android-xx" when "xx" is your API version.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

1. Click Android SDK Manager
2. Download Android 4.2.2 (Api 17)

[image]

3. After install Android 4.2.2(Api 17)
4. Click right on project --> Properties --> Android --> Target Build Target
5. Choose Android 4.2.2 Api 17.
6. Finish